Simply join 2 tables without condition and cross join, MySQL
table 1:



value




a


b



table 2:



value




c


d


e



I need to get this result:



value
value




a
c


b
d


NULL
e



So, it's like Simple join, when row from 1st table matches corresponding(by order) row in 2nd table without any condition.
As a kind of workaround, I thought out this one:
SELECT value, "table1" AS src FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT value, "table2" AS src FROM t2

which gives:



value
src




a
table1


b
table1


c
table2


d
table2


e
table2



In general it's appropriate, but can it be done as I showed in necessary result above?

You write "by order", but your sample data doesn't contain any columns to use for an order. You need a timestamp or a id column, don't you? How else do you want to sort?

You are joining on the rows' position (row number) in both datasets. In the absence of a full outer join in mysql, such query would be everything, but simple join.

@Shadow Without a column which can be used to sort, there is no row's position ;)

@JonasMetzler any column can be sorted...

I bet the sample data is not representative..

Sure can you sort every column, that was not my point.

@JonasMetzler then what was your point?

My point was I doubt the example represents the real use case (as P.Salmon also mentioned), so it could be misleading. Yes, you could do something as explained in the answer without an explicit column you use to sort the result. But I doubt this is really intended and think OP might have missed to mention another column they can use for a proper sort.

You did not mention any column which will define the order, in that case value column is used to add a ordering using ROW_NUMBER().

CTE table1_with_rownum and table2_with_rownum will assign the order.
These datasets are then joined based on rownum so that order is maintained and the result sets are unioned to remove any duplicates.

Fiddle
WITH table1_with_rownum AS (
    SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS rownum
    FROM table1
),
table2_with_rownum AS (
    SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value) AS rownum
    FROM table2
)

SELECT 
    t1.value AS value1, 
    t2.value AS value2
FROM table1_with_rownum t1
LEFT JOIN table2_with_rownum t2 ON t1.rownum = t2.rownum 

UNION

SELECT 
    t1.value AS value1, 
    t2.value AS value2
FROM table1_with_rownum t1
RIGHT JOIN table2_with_rownum t2 ON t1.rownum = t2.rownum
ORDER BY value1;

Output


Note: In the question, the expected result has the row with value1 = NULL as last row, in your answer as first row. I don't know if it matters for them. In case it should appear as last row, then change your ORDER BY clause to ORDER BY -value1 DESC

Another note: To use UNION might be slow because it requires time to remove duplicates. Therefore, UNION ALL should be prefered. You can add WHERE t1.value IS NULL to your second query to avoid unwanted rows appear in the result.

Use UNION over ROW_NUMBER result and join to it. https://dbfiddle.uk/aIBRofzj

@Akina, very nice, thanks

Thanks a lot @JonasMetzler and akina for the sharing the optimisations! :)
